# How can i use query in mongoose array object Schema?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mF8Sx.png)

this is my Schema

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2p4BS.png)

i want to use tag.id

this is code doesnt work....
help me

Comment: you might sending `id` as string since the `_id` is the type of `ObjectId` in your schema so try to convert your `id` to type of `ObjectId`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using positional operator in this case.

```
Todo.find({ 'tag.$._id': id });
```